# sudo su "username" vs. su "username"

Tags: sudo, su

Please explain me, what is the difference between: **sudo su "username"** vs. **su "username"**

Which has higher privileges? If I log into root with **sudo su "username"**, I am root for one command only? So it can be that the beginning of the script works fine, but the rest doesn't?
So in this case **su "username"** is suggested, because it has higher privileges? Please explain me the difference between the 2 commands, thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are the differences:

- `su <someuser>` starts a shell for user `someuser`. Unless you're root, you'll be asked the password for `someuser`.
- `su` (without username) start a shell for user `root` (after asking for the root password).
- `sudo` asks for your password and (assuming you have sudo rights) executes a command with root privileges (`sudo reboot` asks for your password and reboots the computer).
- `sudo su <somesuer>` executes `su` with root privileges. So it doesn't ask for `someuser`'s password. It will however ask for *your* password to verify your sudo rights. After that it will start a shell *for user someuser*.

*In terms of privileges*, there is no difference for the shell that is opened by `sudo su <someuser>` or by `su <someuser>`. This *isn't* a security issue, as the shell process can't escalate to the privileges of the parent process.

You **can** see the difference if you look at the process tree. `sudo su <someuser>` shows (assuming bash):

```
+───bash───su───bash
```

While `su <someuser>` shows:

```
+───bash───sudo───su───bash
```

Your next question is probably how to pass a password in an unattended script, which doesn't require user input. I think there are two options:

- Run the script from cron (or any variant thereof) and run it as root
- Run the script from your own account and use the -S option of sudo like this: `echo <yourpassword> | sudo -S su -l <someuser>` or even better: `echo <yourpassword> | sudo -S su -l <someuser> -c '<somecommand>'`. Make sure the script is only readable by yourself, as your password is in it. More indirectly, you can store your password in a file and cat it to sudo. Then your script can be readable, but your password file can't be.

Comment: When you're starting a shell as a different user, it's useful to use the command `su - <someuser>`.  That will load all that user's normal environment.  There might be times you don't want that, but if you're trying to troubleshoot a problem a user is having, having his/her environment just like they normally have can be handy.

Comment: But as I understood, if I want to start a shell as a different user, there is no significant difference between su <someuser> and sudo su <someuser>. Both commands give you the same privileges. So my script.sh should run successfully in both cases. Or is there any difference? Can it be that script runs successfully with su <someuser> but don't with sudo su <someuser>?

Comment: Yes. sudo asks for your password. If it doesn't get one, it exits. So, use su instead of sudo su. Sudo su doesn't add anything.

Comment: The difference is that you do not need to know <someuser>'s password if you have root privileges, which `sudo su` gives you. To use `su` without `sudo` you need to know the user's password. Once logged on the environment is the same. If you can't run `sudo`, but know the root password, you can use `su` then `su <someuser>` and this will again allow you to log on as <someuser> without knowing his/her password.

Comment: @AFH: absolutely true. I'll add that to the answer.